# Getting result from Maximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to get maximization result from Maximize function to use it in later calculations.
At the moment I use the following code:

```
c := 4
p[q1_, q2_] := 12 - q1 - q2
pi[p_, q_] := p*q - c*q
q2optimal := Maximize[pi[p[q1, q2], q2], q2][[2]][[1]][[2]]
q2optimal
poptimal := Simplify[p[q1, q2optimal]]
poptimal
```

Is there any other way to get the same result without that ugly `[[2]][[1]][[2]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for one, you can put all the *accessors* into one `[[..]]`:

```
Maximize[pi[p[q1, q2], q2], q2][[2, 1, 2]]
```

The second way is to use the rule `->` in the *last* part the result directly

```
q2 /. Last@Maximize[pi[p[q1, q2], q2], q2]
```

The result from functions like `Maximize`, `NMaximize`, `Minimize` or even `Solve` might look strange for a beginner, but *rules* and *replacement* are one of the core concepts of *Mathematica*. Therefore, you should [read this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html) to get used to it.

Btw, is there a particular reason why you use `:=` in your simple assignments?

Comment: Thank for the explanation!
I use `:=` because it does what I need - it defines a function.

Comment: And thanks for the link to tutorial. I definitely need it. :(

Comment: @user4510038 Just make sure you are [aware of the difference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/avid6.png) between `=` and `:=`. For functions like `p` it is (almost always) the right way, for variables like `c` you might experience unexpected behaviour.